# Update objects in a Scene without re-creating it

Tags: rendering, linked-data, scene

I am making a template file setup that contains various render settings, render layers, etc. Objects will be linked into this file to create shots for a project. Part of the setup is that the file contains two Scenes with different settings. The second Scene links all the objects of the first, but has different render engine, render settings, etc.

When you create a linked scene, it links all the existing objects in the first scene. However, if the linked scene already exists, it does not get any new objects you add to the first scene. This means that to get my objects linked, i need to do it manually, or I need to re-create the linked scene, which will mean manually re-doing all its different settings.

I'm looking for a way to update/link all the objects from the first Scene into the Second Scene so that I don't have to manually do either part. Does this sort of thing exist anywhere? What would a script need to do to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Linking scenes will not update automatically. You need to use Background scenes.
[image]

In a background scene all the changes are directly available. But be aware that some parts of blender will not work as expected. Like physics between background and foreground objects. But if it is just render engine and settings it can be a solution.